# Issues compiling a directX project to a .exe

Tags: c++, directx

Having some real issues compiling my directX shader project to an executable. I've done everything I normally do, link all the libraries needed, put the required assets in the release folder but still the .exe crashes on once run.

[image]

I've tired everything I can think of, Its driving me insane as I've complied a directX project before and it was not this hard!

Comment: Where in your code does it crash?

Comment: The issue is not a compilation issue. The fault occurs at runtime. Use your debugging tools to diagnose what is happening. At the very least do better than "it crashes".

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your issue is not a compilation issue but a run-time issue.

Without seeing your code, there is no way to determine what the issue is. But I would use the DirectX Sample as a base and move forward from there.